# How to programmatically click an ApplicationBarIconButton?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, appbar

So that's the question. I have the following variants of code in my test framework (assuming appBarButton is ApplicationBarIconButton):

```
var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var method = typeof(ApplicationBarIconButton)
             .GetMethod("ClickEvent", bindingFlags);

if (method != null)
{
    method.Invoke(appBarButton, null);
}
```

or

```
IInvokeProvider invokableButton;
var isInvokable = (invokableButton = appBarButton as IInvokeProvider) != null;
if (isInvokable)
{
    invokableButton.Invoke();
}
```

Both pieces are not working. So I want to find some workarounds to programmatically click the ApplicationBarIconButton. Any help?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the reason for perform a click programmatically. Why don't you rise the event or call de method called by the click event?

Comment: I want to extend the existing test framework ([link](https://github.com/Expensify/WindowsPhoneTestFramework)) to automate some steps. This framework seems to behave incorrectly in some cases, where AppBar is involved into.

Comment: Ah, ok I understood. I don't know if it is possible, because AppBar is exposed by PhoneApplicationPage class and managed by the Phone Shell.

Comment: You can't do that because the Click is an Eventhandler and only exposed Add/Remove. You could create an ApplicationBarManager that handles the creation of buttons and keep a log of the registered handlers, but that just seems wrong to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI automation, the bane of developers. For some strange reason, you cannot automate application bar buttons. But, if you can modify the application's source code, you can employ the following trick. First, create a new class:

```
public class CustomApplicationBarIconButton : ApplicationBarIconButton
{
    public new event EventHandler Click;

    public void RaiseClick()
    {
        if (Click != null)
            Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now, in your XAML replace `shell:ApplicationBarIconButton` with `wp8App:CustomApplicationBarIconButton` and you can now automate such buttons.

Unfortunately, you cannot programmatically replace such buttons since you cannot extract event handlers and switch them. And accessing any private methods/fields is forbidden by the platform.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I already implemented my own class for it, using commands instead of event handlers (just for MVVM compatibility) and it works like a charm.